# Group matches and non-matches from regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

The script that I am working on currently performs three regular expression searches in a file; consider the following as input:

```
2018-01-22 04.02.03: Wurk: 98745061 (12345678)
 Replies (pos: 2) are missing/not sent on assignment: Asdf (55461)

2018-01-22 04.02.03: Wurk: 98885612 (87654321)
 Gorp: 98885612 is not registered for arrival!
 Brork: 98885612 is not registered for arrival!

2018-01-22 04.02.08: Wurk: 88855521 (885052)
 Blam: 12365479 is not registered for arrival!
 Fork: 56564123 is not registered for arrival!

2018-01-22 04.02.08: Wurk: A0885521 (885052)
 Blam: 12365479 is not registered for arrival!
 Fork: 56564123 is not registered for arrival!
```

where each regular expression finds the rows in the file according to the date of the row, as well as the first number after Wurk:, and collects the eight digits/characters after Wurk:.

```
import time, glob, re
logpath = glob.glob('path\\to\\log*.log')[0]
readfile = open(logpath, "r")
daysdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
nine = []
eight = []
seven = []
no_match = []
for line in readfile:
    for match in re.finditer(daysdate + r'.*Wurk: (9.{7})', line):
        nine.append(match.group(1))
    for match in re.finditer(daysdate + r'.*Wurk: (8.{7})', line):
        eight.append(match.group(1))
    for match in re.finditer(daysdate + r'.*Wurk: (7.{7})', line):
        seven.append(match.group(1))
print("\nNine:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str, nine)) +
   "\nEight:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str, eight)) +
   "\nSeven:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str, seven)) +
   "\nNo matches found:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str, no_match)))
```

This currently gives the output of:

```
Nine:
98745061,
98885612

Eight:
88855521

Seven:

No matches found:
```

Now, the issue at hand is figuring out how to make a regular expression that matches the eight digits/characters after Wurk:, which were not matched in any previous regular expressions. The new output should therefore be:

```
Nine:
98745061,
98885612

Eight:
88855521

Seven:

No matches found:
A0885521
```

**TL;DR**

How do you match regular expressions that do not match criteria for previous regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex isn't intended to group data; it's intended to *find* data. Use regex to extract the values, and then use code to group them:

```
seven, eight, nine, no_match = [], [], [], []

wurk_map = {'7': seven,
            '8': eight,
            '9': nine}

wurks = re.findall(r'(?<=Wurk: ).{8}', text)
for wurk in wurks:
    wurk_map.get(wurk[0], no_match).append(wurk)

print(seven)     # []
print(eight)     # ['88855521']
print(nine)      # ['98745061', '98885612']
print(no_match)  # ['A0885521']
```